# ListView Item Click Open Custom Dialog with Another Custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialog, customdialog

Here I have created custom dialog which includes listview with single choice mode. when user selects one of the item in listview then it should be selected when dialog is opened next time and user must be able to select another item also. Butmy problem is dialog radiobutton are unchecked when dialog is reopened. I have reffered the http://blog.thisisfeifan.com/2011/10/2-lines-text-in-single-choice-listview.html

So what is wrong in my code ?

My custom Dialog xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"    
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

     <LinearLayout android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_width="250dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical">

     <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv_MainText"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:paddingLeft="12dp" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/rb_Choice" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:focusable="false"  android:clickable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:paddingRight="12dp">
      </RadioButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom Dialog Listview file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="250dp"
   android:layout_height="210dp">

   <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/layout_btn"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="3dp"
         android:gravity="center">          
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/separator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dialoglist"
        />        
  </LinearLayout>
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialoglist"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
        android:divider="#242424"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" 
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

In my main activity I am having listview and on list item click i have opened the custom dialog :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                if(position == 1)
                {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);


                    dialog.setTitle("Select Font Size");

                    final String[] sizeType = new String[] {"Normal" , "Medium" , "Large" , "Extra Large"};
                    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> m_data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
                    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> m_data_new = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

                    final HashMap<String, Object> data_new = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < sizeType.length;i++)
                    {
                        HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        data.put("item1",sizeType[i]);

                        m_data.add(data);

                    }

                        for (HashMap<String, Object> m :m_data) //make data of this view should not be null (hide )

                        {
                                m.put("checked", false);

                        }

                    final ListView lst = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
                    //lst.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

                     final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, m_data, R.layout.dialoglist_item,new String[] {"item1","checked"},new int[] {R.id.tv_MainText,R.id.rb_Choice}); 
                     lst.setAdapter(adapter);

                     lst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int item, long arg3) {
                            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rb_Choice);
                            if (!rb.isChecked()) //OFF->ON
                            {                       
                                for (HashMap<String, Object> m :m_data) //clean previous selected
                                    m.put("checked", false);

                                m_data.get(item).put("checked", true);              
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            }       

                            selectedSize = sizeType[item];
                            //dialog.dismiss();

                        }

                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
```

So please solve my problem. Thanx in advance.

Comment: i'm having trouble getting a handle on how this is supposed to work? would it be alot to ask for a picture of the dialog? with the radiobutton?

Comment: It seems similar to the alert dialog with radio button.

Comment: so what do you want to be saved? if the 1 button was clicked or not?

Comment: I want to save the state of the radio button whether it is checked or not. If it is checked then when i open the dialog next time,that radio button should be checked.

Comment: and by next time, do you mean in the same session or even after the app is closed and open again?

Comment: even after the application closed and open again , it shuld show previous selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simply saving a value to persist app sessions you can use the `SharedPreferences` API:
Here's a sample of saving:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isChecked", rb.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
```

where `rb` is your radioButton. and to retrieve it and apply it next time, you can use:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
    rb.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("isChecked", false));
```

Note that `false` here is simply a default value in case a value with that key doesn't exist the sharedPrefs file yet. It will automatically create one if not existing.