# SharedPreference use in custom dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have created activity which extends preferenceActivity. In that activity I have opened custom dialog which shows list of item. Whenever i click on item in listview , dialog closed. At that time i want to store the selected item in SharedPreference so that i an get that item in application wide.

But my problem is How do i store that selected item in SharedPreference ??

And when i open my application next time, i should able to retrive previous seleced item.

Here is my code for PreferenceActivity :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener 
{
    SharedPreferences myprefs;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        Preference prefereces=findPreference("alertdialog_Font_Style");
        prefereces.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DialogFontStyle objdialog = new DialogFontStyle(SettingsActivity.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
                objdialog.show();
                return true;
            }


        });
    }
```

Here is my class for dialog :

```
public class DialogFontStyle extends Dialog {

    public DialogFontStyle(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

        final String[] sizeType = new String[] {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d"};       

            final ListView lst = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sizeType);                  
         lst.setAdapter(adapter);

             lst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    dismiss();
                }
             });
    } 
}
```

Please give me some solution to store data in sharedpreference.
Thanx.

Comment: it gets no clearer than what i wrote a couple days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523823/listview-item-click-open-custom-dialog-with-another-custom-listview/13526006#13526006. is there something that wasn't persisting in that example?

Comment: is it solved zanky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write something to share preferences use this code:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( mContext );
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean( KEY, VALUE );
editor.commit();
```

mContext should be context of your activity or application not dialog. Or if your dialog is within your activity use `SettingsActivity.this` or create class member mContext and initi in on `onCreate()`

Comment: In Dialog's `onItemClicked()`

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- Instead of making a custom dialog, you could extend the [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) class to customize its appearence or behavior, but relying on the default mechanisms used for [settings screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html). The saving would be then managed by the ListPreference superclass.
- You can store the preference manually by getting the shared preferences calling the Context.getSharedPreferences() method, and then obtain and [Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) that will allow you to put values in the shared preferences and commit those changes.

To retrieve the previously stored item, you only need to obtain the SharedPreferences object again and call the desired get..() method to get the previously stored key.

Comment: can you please give me some idea about how do i extend listpreference and make list ?

Comment: You can take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom. But if you only need list of text strings you can use the ListPreference itself. You can then specify the localized strings to be shown and the values associated with each of them.